# Conditions for measure being finite and $\sigma$-finite

Tags: measure-theory

working on a problem for measure theory and wanted to see if I'm on the right track.

I've shown that over a measurable space $(X,\mathcal M)$, $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\mu_j$ where {$\mu_j$}$_{j=1}^\infty$ a sequence of measures, and {$a_j$}$_{j=1}^\infty \subset (0,\infty)$ is a measure.

Now I'm trying to find the conditions for which a specific example of this measure is *finite*, and *$\sigma$-finite*, the measure being $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\delta_{x_j}$$ where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac measure.

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\delta_{x_j}(X)$ = $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j$ since each $\delta_{x_j}$ = $1$ over the entire set X, and condition for finiteness of this measure should be the sum being finite. Is this correct?

Secondly, for $\sigma$-finiteness, my intuition tells me that X should be countable, since the Dirac measure is similar to the counting measure, but I'm not sure how to formally show conditions for finiteness or $\sigma$-finiteness.

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finiteness part is correct. The measure is always $\sigma$-finite. Each $x_j$ has finite measure (namely $a_j$) and $X = (\cup_j \{x_j\})\cup (X\setminus \cup_j \{x_j\})$ where $X\setminus \cup_j \{x_j\}$ is measurable with measure $0$.

Comment: For the finiteness part, does it suffice to write what I have above to show that it's the condition for being finite? (i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j<\infty$). Also, could you elaborate a bit more on the second part - is X countable the only condition, or do I need $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j<infty$ as well?

Comment: Sorry, I needlessly added the $\sum a_j < \infty$ condition for sigma-finiteness. For the finiteness part, the point is that you want to show $\mu(A) < \infty$ for each measurable $A \subseteq X$. Since everything is monotone, showing that is equivalent to showing $\mu(X) < \infty$. But, as you noted, $\mu(X) = \sum_n a_n$.

Comment: Would I need to frame these in an "if and only if" way to show that the conditions for finiteness and $\sigma$-finiteness are as above?

Comment: For finiteness, yes: $\mu$ is finite iff $\mu(A) < \infty$ for each measurable $A \subseteq X$ iff $\mu(X) < \infty$. For $\sigma$-finiteness, no. $X$ can be uncountable. I updated my answer.

Comment: Not sure if I follow that it's always $\sigma$-finite. Couldn't a subset $A_n$ have a countably infinite # of elements such that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\delta_{x_j}$ becomes infinite?

Comment: That doesn't matter. The definition of $\sigma$-finite means that there exist measurable $(A_n)_n$ with $\mu(A_n) < \infty$ for each $n$ and $X = \cup_n A_n$.

Comment: couldn't $\mu(A_n)$=$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\delta_{x_j}(A_n)$ go to $\infty$ if it has countably infinite elements?

Comment: I'm taking $A_n = \{x_n\}$ which gives $\mu(A_n) = a_n < \infty$. lol, its annoying notation, but "another" $A_n$ is $X\setminus \cup_j \{x_j\}$

Comment: Can we do this because the condition for $\sigma$-finiteness is the "existence" of a collection such that $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ and $\bigcup(A_n)$ = $X$ - thus we can construct a collection that unions into X, each with finite measure, and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\delta_{x_j}$ is always $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Yes. I mean that's the whole definition of $\sigma$-finite. If you wanted the condition to hold for all choices of $A_n$, then you can just take $A_1 = X$ and then you'll need $\mu$ to be a finite measure.

Comment: I can just take $A_n$=${x_n}$ argue that it's always $\sigma$-finite then. And for finiteness I would have to argue iff?

Comment: Yes. See my previous comment.

Comment: certainly! Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention that ${x_j}$ an infinite sequence are distinct elements of X. That wouldn't affect the proof though, right?

Comment: It does not affect the proof.